# What is wrong with this IF statement in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to only show comments if there are any comments as when there are no comments the for loop shows this (the hash table at the bottom) [image: What comments show with no comments]

The if statement in my code is

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% if @article.comments.any? %>

<%= @article.comments.each do |comment| %>

<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.comment %>
 </p>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What is wrong with my code that it still enters the for loop even when there are no comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= ... %>` will output itself because you specify the equal sign (`=`) after `<%`, if you specify the minus sign (`-`) it will not output itself, or simply no sign, just `<%`. I personally prefer to specify `-` as it declares your intention (and SLIM uses `-` as well)

```
<%- @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You've likely built a new comment on the article in order for that create comment form to work above it, so the crux of the problem comes down to `any?` will look in the in-memory association if it exists, as seen in the following example:

```
article = Article.create!
=> #<Article id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-05 02:08:31", updated_at: "2017-07-05 02:08:31">
article.comments.any?
=> false
article.comments.build
=> #<Comment id: nil, article_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
article.comments.any?
=> true
article.comments.exists?
=> false
```

That's why you're entering the conditional in the first place, and then as others have pointed out, you're outputting the results of the loop (all records iterated) afterwards.

To fix this, you can use `exists?` instead (as also seen in the example on the last line) which will check the database and not included the one you just built for the form.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to rails and '.exists?' is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

The line that is causing the problem: `<%= @article.comments.each do |comment| %>`. You don't need to use `<%= %>` while iterating through the comments of an article. `<% %>` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

In erb templates,
`<%   %>` used  to execute ruby code (loops, calculations, variable assignments, etc)
`<%=  %>` used to print something into resulting HTML template
`<%#  %>` used for comments (not printed on generated HTML) on erb templates

So, your erb file should look like this:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% if @article.comments.any? %>
  <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Commenter:</strong>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Comment:</strong>
      <%= comment.comment %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```